# What's the meaning of "relief efforts (Noun+Noun)"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

She coordinated the **relief efforts** in the Sudan.

What's the meaning of "relief efforts" here?

I think it means- attempts/initiatives to give/provide     help/food/money etc.

Am I correct as to my interpretation?

Comment: 1. The title is in error: in English, a word may be used as more than one part of speech. See any dictionary, e.g. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relief#dictionary-entry-1, to see the different usage. 2, Your assumption is reasonable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convenience food or convenient food？](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/336683/convenience-food-or-convenient-food)

Comment: Your interpretation is correct : It means *humanitarian aid*.